# get last row empty row with formula's

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to get the last empty row in my spreadsheet. But what i get is the last row, without a formula.

I use the script to add a new row. The cells in this row are needed for calculations in  and the cells in this row 
I use getLastRow()

Is there a way to get the Last empty row, what isn't looking at formula's (the visible last empty row)

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Comment: Loop through all rows and make a string out of every row (replacing comma's with "") . Then check the length. If the length is zero the row is empty. Break out of the loop and exit the script.

Comment: How about getMaxRows()?

Comment: @RobinGertenbach that would work, but isn't what I'm looking for

Comment: Oh, so you want a function that returns the row index of the last row containing a formula that returns `""`?

Comment: @JPV I'm working on the loopthing. But I didn't found out yet how to detect if a cell in a row is empty

Comment: @RobinGertenbach  I need to add a new row on the end in the same way Google forms add a row.  In the sheet I add sales lines and I want to see totals and some other stuff. There fore I have in the sheet already formula's. on every row. To let it work correctly I need to know the last row what is added.

Comment: I am not sure what the problem is. `getLastRow()` will retrieve the last non-empty row. If you want the first empty row, you just need `getLastRow()+1`. `getMaxRow()` will return the last row available in the sheet regardless of it being empty or not

Comment: @Vytautas  GetLastRow()  gives the last empty row. But what if the row contains a just a formula without data cells?   Anyway. I've figure it out that it's a common issue and GetLastRow() isn't the way to go for this. There are other solutions to solve this Problem, like with arrayformula

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick example

```
 /*main code (example) */

 function myCode() {

 var sheet, firstFreeRow;

 sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("sheet2");
 firstFreeRow = getLastRowInRange(sheet, 'A:D') + 1
 Logger.log(firstFreeRow)
 }

 /*Helper function: takes sheet object and range as parameters and returns the last row with data of that range.

 function getLastRowInRange(sheetObj, range) {

 var data, rowN; 

 data = sheetObj.getRange(range).getValues();
 rowN;
 for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
     if (data[i].toString().replace(/,/g, "").length == 0) {
         rowN = i;
         break;
     }
 }
 return rowN;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out these links.
https://exceljet.net/formula/get-value-of-last-non-empty-cell

http://excel.tips.net/T002103_Referencing_the_Last_Cell_in_a_Column.html

I was able to use this code in my Gsheet to do what you are saying and it worked just fine.

=INDIRECT("B"&COUNTA(B:B))